# WebStorm cannot find npm

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm

I recently updated to WebStorm 2020.3 and I'm getting the following error: `Cannot resolve 'npm' package manager` which wasn't the case before the upgrade.

I've verified that npm is installed on my system:

```
 9:12am /Users/paymahn/sagebackend notify.of.payments ⬆ ⬇ ✭ ✱ ◼
 ❯❯❯ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
 9:12am /Users/paymahn/sagebackend notify.of.payments ⬆ ⬇ ✭ ✱ ◼
 ❯❯❯ npm -v
7.0.10
```

I've also tried manually pointing WebStorm at `/usr/local/bin/npm` but that didn't seem to help because `/usr/local/bin/npm` is a symlink. I've tried pointing WebStorm to the symlinked file

[image]

but got the following error when executing `npm run test` through the IDE from the following `package.json`:

```
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --max-warnings=0 .",
        "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
        "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
        "start": "npm run shell",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
        "logs": "firebase functions:log",
        "prettier": "npx prettier --write .",
        "test": "mocha --reporter spec"
    },
```

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node/15.2.1/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js test --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto

> test
> mocha --reporter spec

env: node: No such file or directory
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/paymahn/sagebackend/functions
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c mocha --reporter spec
```

However, I can successfully run tests from the command line:

```
 9:19am /Users/paymahn/sagebackend/functions  ✘ 1 notify.of.payments ⬆ ⬇ ✭ ✱ ◼
 ❮❮❮ npm run test

> test
> mocha --reporter spec



  0 passing (1ms)
```

How can I successfully execute npm commands from WebStorm?

Comment: Oh, looks like starting webstorm from the terminal has fixed it: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000749210-Get-env-node-No-such-file-or-directory-error-when-run-babel-in-Intellij?page=1#community_comment_115000620244

I wonder why this is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, it seems that quitting webstorm and starting it just once from the terminal seems to have solved the problem. Now I can launch webstorm using Alfred or Spotlight and the issue doesn't pop up again.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000749210-Get-env-node-No-such-file-or-directory-error-when-run-babel-in-Intellij?page=1#community_comment_115000620244